# how to provide docker image in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-batch

when setting up a job definition in aws batch, I can specify a container image. can i directly specify my image from the docker hub repo ?

I have created a public docker hub repo, but i'm not sure if aws will pull the image directly from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I don't see why it would not work. Since **AWS Batch uses ECS**,  the following options are allowed for [Images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_image) in ECS (among other things):

> Images in official repositories on **Docker Hub** use a single name (for example, ubuntu or mongo).

> Images in other repositories on **Docker Hub** are qualified with an organization name (for example, amazon/amazon-ecs-agent).

Comment: cool thanks. one thing i forgot to mention in my question, is it possible to  set up a S3, and pass its location  to the container?

Comment: @tisha Yes. You can use [environmental variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_environment) to pass options to the containers.

Comment: thanks again. I do have few follow up questions, i can open a new question for it is related to same question. I am also new to AWS so , if i set up S3, is it a public URL for S3 i provide as a parameter and when I set up the AWS batch, how do i make sure it has access to that S3.

Comment: @tisha There are task roles for that. But you can make new question as it seems as a new issue :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can specify an image from Docker Hub, there is no such restriction in ECS and AWS Batch Job.

> For Container image, choose the Docker image to use for your job. **Images in the Docker Hub registry are available by default.** You can also specify other repositories with `repository-url/image:tag`. Up to 255 letters (uppercase and lowercase), numbers, hyphens, underscores, colons, periods, forward slashes, and number signs are allowed. This parameter maps to Image in the Create a container section of the Docker Remote API and the IMAGE parameter of docker run.

If you mentioned image with single name like

```
nginx:latest
```

The job will pull image from Docker hub.